# Why is my gdb debugger setting 2 break points?

Tags: gdb, debugging

Is this normal? I swear it was setting only 1 break point until recently. How do I make it only set a breakpoint in my running file and not the source file.

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1dbf
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1ed8: file arrays.c, line 17.
warning: Multiple breakpoints were set.
Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted breakpoints.
(gdb)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDB: warning: Multiple breakpoints were set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330364/gdb-warning-multiple-breakpoints-were-set)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple main symbols :) Perhaps look at 'info breakpoints' in gdb or

```
objdump -C -t myprog
```

to see why/where.

Use cscope to interactively search for declarations.

```
ctags -R . && grep -w main tags
[ -x /usr/bin/vim ] && vim +'tj main'
```

Should be helpful as well if you have ctags (and optionally, vim) installed

If all else fails, brute force `grep -RIw main .` should work. If even that fails, you should find yourself with very strange external header #defines or even a (static) library with a surplus main symbol. To *brute force* search for the `main` identifier through the preprocessed sources:

```
find -name '*.c'    -print0 | xargs -0n1 -iQ cpp -I/usr/include/... -DDEBUG Q Q.ii
find -name '*.c.ii' -print0 | xargs grep -wI main
```

(*replace `-I/usr/include/... -DDEBUG` with the relevant preprocessor defines*)