# GDB: warning: Multiple breakpoints were set on overloaded methods

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~> g++ -Wall -pedantic breakpoints.cpp -g
anisha@linux-dopx:~> gdb a.out
(gdb) b X::X
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ac1: file breakpoints.cpp, line 14.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400aa0: file breakpoints.cpp, line 9.
warning: Multiple breakpoints were set.
Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted breakpoints.
(gdb)
```

What is the way to set the breakpoint
on the default constructor, such that
GDB doesn't create unnecessary breakpoints
on the its overloaded counterparts?

Or is it a problem with GDB that it expects
the users to delete its mess?
Or am I missing a point?

**EDIT 1.**

For the following code:

```
class X
{
    public:
        X   () 
        {
            std :: cout << "\nIn the default constructor";
        }

        X   (int) 
        {
            std :: cout << "\nIn the parameterized constructor";
        }

        ~X () {}
};
```

I tried:

```
(gdb) b X:: X (11)
the class X does not have any method named X (11)
Hint: try 'X:: X (11)<TAB> or 'X:: X (11)<ESC-?>
(Note leading single quote.)
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

Didn't help!

**EDIT 2.**

Thanks to *osgx*, the following works:

```
(gdb) b X::X(int)
Breakpoint 5 at 0x400ac1: file breakpoints.cpp, line 14.
(gdb) b X::X()
Breakpoint 6 at 0x400aa0: file breakpoints.cpp, line 9.
(gdb)
```

Comment: What CPU has linux-dopx?

Comment: @osgx didn't understand what info you want.

Comment: Is the linux-dopx based on x86 or x86_64 CPU? Or is it ARM?

Comment: Okay :) `anisha@linux-dopx:~> uname -a
Linux linux-dopx 2.6.34-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2010-06-29 02:39:08 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, this case is normal. Some ABI will generate two constructors for an Class. When you ask `b X::X` gdb will detect both constructors and set two breakpoints. (Sorry, this is not your case)

The "Multiple breakpoints were set." warning may be also given for overloaded methods (this is your case): http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_36.html

> Some programming languages (notably C++) permit a single function name to be defined several times, for application in different contexts. This is called overloading. When a function name is overloaded, `break function' is not enough to tell GDB where you want a breakpoint.

For such methods you can select one method by typing its types:

> break function(types)

Update: According to the same document, gdb should ask user to select some of overloaded methods:

> GDB offers you a menu of numbered choices for different possible breakpoints, and waits for your selection with the prompt `>'. The first two options are always` [0] cancel' and `[1] all'. Typing 1 sets a breakpoint at each definition of function, and typing 0 aborts the break command without setting any new breakpoints.
>
> For example, the following session excerpt shows an attempt to set a breakpoint at the overloaded symbol String::after. We choose three particular definitions of that function name:

```
(gdb) b String::after
[0] cancel
[1] all
[2] file:String.cc; line number:867
[3] file:String.cc; line number:860
[4] file:String.cc; line number:875
[5] file:String.cc; line number:853
[6] file:String.cc; line number:846
[7] file:String.cc; line number:735
> 2 4 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb26c: file String.cc, line 867.
Breakpoint 2 at 0xb344: file String.cc, line 875.
Breakpoint 3 at 0xafcc: file String.cc, line 846.
Multiple breakpoints were set.
Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted
 breakpoints.
(gdb)
```

UPDATE1: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Ambiguous-Expressions.html#Ambiguous-Expressions says that this menu can be switched on and off (default is off):

> set multiple-symbols *mode*
>
> This option allows you to adjust the debugger behavior when an expression is ambiguous.
> By default, mode is set to **all**. If the command with which the expression is used allows more than one choice, then gdb automatically selects all possible choices.
>
> When mode is set to **ask**, the debugger always uses the menu when an ambiguity is detected.
>
> Finally, when mode is set to **cancel**, the debugger reports an error due to the ambiguity and the command is aborted.

Comment: It doesn't make sense of GDB to set 10 break points on 10 overloaded functions, when only 1 is needed and then expect the users to delete the mess, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: The problem here is how can GDB know what user wants. Some users want to set breakpoint to all overloaded versions and some users want only set breakpoint to some versions. If user gives `Ambiguous Expression` (function name without arguments), gdb will set breakpoint to all versions (but, see Update1, gdb may ask you what to do). If user gives function name with arguments, gdb will set only single breakpoint. GDB just do the best trying to unredstand user.

Comment: not a number, but a type. For example:  `b X::X()`,  `b X::X(int)`

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks. I will put the output in the first post.